# How to change globally the Fonts in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I’m trying to find a way to globally change the font in a FireMonkey project.
What is the easiest way to do it without having to change the font property for all the components?
If there a way to set the font of an entire application or an entire form (like in VCL)?

Comment: what have you tried? It seems that the new XE2 "live bindings" system might be useful for doing things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with Duck Duck Delphi...

This would change all of the fonts for components on a form:

```
Form1.duck.all.on('Font').setTo('Name','Arial').setTo('Color',TAlphaColors.Red);
```

And I haven't tried it, but either of these "should" work for doing the same application-wide:

```
Application.duck.all.each.on('Font').setTo('Name','Arial').setTo('Color',TAlphaColors.Red);
Screen.duck.all.each.on('Font').setTo('Name','Arial').setTo('Color',TAlphaColors.Red);
```

Duck Duck Delphi can be found here:

https://bitbucket.org/sivv/duckduckdelphi

Comment: Broken link. Now appears to reside at: https://github.com/deadserious/duckduckdelphi. But not updated in 5 years?

Answer (score 1):

FireMonkey [styles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles) are the way to do this. Note that the VCL way of doing things with `ParentXXX` is not offered in FMX.

This [article](http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/delphi/firemonkey_styles/firemonkey_styles.html) covers the topic in some detail.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just to set a new  TFont.FontService , you can change default font size and 
family 



unit ChangeDefaultFont; 

interface
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,FMX.graphics;

type
TDefaultFont = class (TInterfacedObject, IFMXSystemFontService)
public
  function GetDefaultFontFamilyName: string;
  function GetDefaultFontSize: Single;
end;

implementation

{ TDefaultFont }

function TDefaultFont.GetDefaultFontFamilyName: string;
begin
  Result := 'Tahoma';
end;

function TDefaultFont.GetDefaultFontSize: Single;
begin
  Result := 26.0;
end;
initialization
   TFont.FontService := TDefaultFont.Create;
end.
```